# Query runs too slow and even it stops because exceded of time with 17000 rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb, distinct

I have table 1:

| historial_id | timestamp | address | value | insertion_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-29 | 1 | 84 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | 2022-01-29 | 2 | 40 | 2022-01-31 |
| 3 | 2022-01-30 | 1 | 84 | 2022-01-31 |
| 4 | 2022-01-30 | 2 | 41 | 2022-01-31 |
| 5 | 2022-01-30 | 2 | 41 | 2022-01-31 |

(sometimes it has repeated rows)

...

I need a Query to get:

| timestamp | value(address 1) | value(address 2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-29 | 84 | 40 |
| 2022-01-30 | 84 | 41 |

......

I tried with:

```
SELECT timestamp, ( SELECT value 
                   FROM historical 
                   WHERE register_type=11 
                   AND address=2
                   AND timestamp=t1.timestamp
                   GROUP BY value 
                   ) AS CORRIENTE_mA,
                ( SELECT value 
                  FROM historical 
                  WHERE register_type=11 
                  AND address=1 
                  AND timestamp=t1.timestamp 
                  GROUP BY value ) AS Q_M3pH
FROM historical AS t1 
GROUP BY timestamp;
```

But it's too slow, it even stops because of exceeded time.

I tried with `distinct` too instead of `group by`

Comment: Try this query? I changed your subqueries to joins. `SELECT timestamp, h1.value AS CORRIENTE_mA, h2.value AS Q_M3pH FROM historical AS t1 LEFT JOIN historical h1 ON h1.register_type=11 AND h1.address=2 AND h1.timestamp=t1.timestamp LEFT JOIN historical h2 ON h2.register_type=11 AND h2.address=1 AND h2.timestamp=t1.timestamp GROUP BY timestamp;`

Comment: how many row are there in the historical table ?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table historical;` and `select version();`

Comment: your subqueries will produce errors if there is ever more than one value for a given timestamp/register_type/address; can you describe in English what you are trying to accomplish with those subqueries?

Comment: if a timestamp has only rows with register_type _not_ 11, this will produce `timestamp, null, null`; do you actually want to include such rows?

Comment: Ergest Basha's answer is very likely the right approach, but may be improvable depending on your answers to my questions

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `dynamic pivot`.
Please try and avoid [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) like `timestamp`.

Below query return only the max value for address 1 and 2 grouping by  timestamp.

This is a simplified version of your query :

```
select
     `timestamp`
   , max(case when address=1 then value  end) as value_address1
   , max(case when address=2 then value  end) as value_address2

from historical
group by `timestamp`;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
>   timestamp   value_address1  value_address2
>   2022-01-29       84            40
>   2022-01-30       84            41
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d319d170f4b288e4dc224740518a6bec)